# WPF binding to static member

Tags: wpf, binding

Why in the world does this simple thing doesn't work? It is WPF + .NET 4.0 + VB.NET and all I'm trying to accomplish is to bind a ComboBox to a static property of a class:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:CommonLists.JobStatusTypes }}" />
```

Namespace 'local' is imported as:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject1"
```

And the class is:

```
Friend NotInheritable Class CommonLists
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property JobStatusTypes As List(Of JobStatusType)
        Get
            ...
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

BTW, it is executing just fine; only the WPF designer (VS2010) has the issue, telling me that 'Type CommonLists was not found'.

**EDIT:**
The problem appears to be more general than that. I cannot access any of my namespaces in WPF using the xmlns syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Found the answer myself. If I import my namespace like this:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject1;assembly="
```

it appears to work perfectly fine, both with designer and at runtime. I read somewhere that adding **assembly=** (followed by nothing) to your namespace import tells XAML to look in the current assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Member=local:CommonLists.JobStatusTypes}}"
```